# Remove a Button with same text when clicked

Tags: java

I got this assignment where I need to remove a button with the same text when I click on it.
For example if I have 3 button with the word "Word" on it and I click one of them, it will remove all of them from the frame itself.
I most likely not getting the right values on the variables to get their text so that why it doesn't remove them

My code:

```
private String NamesArr[]= {"Yakir","Yarden","Igor","Maoz","Moshe","Israel","Tal","Haim","Nati","Mor","Daniel","Idan"};
private Button ButtonArr[]=new Button[NamesArr.length];
private Font font;

public StudentsGUI(String caption) {
    super(caption);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    font=new Font("Ariel",Font.BOLD,35);

    for(int i=0;i<NamesArr.length;i++) {
        ButtonArr[i]=new Button(" "+NamesArr[(int)(Math.random()*NamesArr.length)]);
        ButtonArr[i].setFont(font);
        ButtonArr[i].addActionListener(this);
        this.add(ButtonArr[i]);
    }
    setLocation(800,500);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==ButtonArr) {
            String btnText=ButtonArr.toString();
        for(int i=0;i<NamesArr.length;i++) {
            if(ButtonArr[i].getLabel().equals(btnText))
                    this.remove(ButtonArr[i]);
            }


    }



}

}
```

Comment: the getText() method should be able to make it work

Comment: The source of the event cannot be an array, so `if(e.getSource()==ButtonArr)` will always be evaluated to `false`

Comment: Where should I implmented the getText() method? on the btnText? is so, doesn't recognize this method.
Also, the source event isn't right? I mean I have other code with same thing that working ( summing up amount of number from sides of buttons )

Comment: `ButtonArr.toString()` returns a String representation of the array. Not the text of a single button. So `if(ButtonArr[i].getLabel().equals(btnText))` will always be evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws in the code of `actionPerformed` as mentioned in the comments. First, to check the source type you must not compare two objects (and in this case two different types) with `==`. Second, retrieve the button text from the actual object. Like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        String btnText = ((Button)e.getSource()).getLabel();
        for(int i=0; i<ButtonArr.length; i++) {
            if (ButtonArr[i].getLabel().equals(btnText)) {
                this.remove(ButtonArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in order to not confuse types with objects, the common coding principle in Java is to start variable names with lower case letters.

Comment: Thank you :)
Still kinda new to coding in overall so I appreciate any tip of information :)

Comment: With that been said, How do I make a button that stands alone not to be deleted?
Should I use variable to count the amount of duplicates?

Comment: You should create a new question on that. Make sure to describe the desired behaviour and the exact problem of your code.

Comment: Aight, will do,.
Thanks.