# Disable Buttons on JAVA but leave unique button alone

Tags: java, awt

According to my previous question here:
[Remove a Button with same text when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862139/remove-a-button-with-same-text-when-clicked/)

I need that the only buttons that appearing more then one will disappearing while clicking on them
Problem is when clicking on the "Unique" ones ( see picture ), they will disappear also.
My code:

```
private String namesArr[] = {"Yakir","Yarden","Igor","Maoz","Moshe","Israel","Tal","Haim","Nati","Mor","Daniel","Idan"};
private Button buttonArr[] = new Button[namesArr.length];
private Font font;

public StudentsGUI(String caption) {
    super(caption);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                    dispose();
                        System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }); 
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    font = new Font("Ariel",Font.BOLD,35);

    for(int i=0;i<namesArr.length;i++) {
        buttonArr[i] = new Button(" "+namesArr[(int)(Math.random()*namesArr.length)]);
        buttonArr[i].setFont(font);
        buttonArr[i].addActionListener(this);
        this.add(buttonArr[i]);
    }
    setLocation(800,500);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        String btnText = ((Button)e.getSource()).getLabel();
        for(int i=0; i<buttonArr.length; i++) {
            if (buttonArr[i].getLabel().equals(btnText)) {
                this.remove(buttonArr[i]);
                pack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The picture to help you understand:
[image]

So if clicking on "Idan", witch is a unique name nothing will happen as it only have one instance,  but if clicking on "Maoz" all the buttons with "Maoz" title will disappear ( this already happening )

Comment: so what is your question and your issue or error exactly ?

Comment: How to make only the those who repeat themselves to disappear ?
The unique ones need to stay, in the picture those who need to stay no matter if click is "Israel" and "Daniel" and "Idan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using collections as per @Freddy's answer should be better. However if you're to stick with arrays, something like below should do it (haven't tested it though)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof Button) {
            String btnText = ((Button)e.getSource()).getLabel();
            int counter = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<buttonArr.length; i++) {
                if (buttonArr[i].getLabel().equals(btnText)) counter++;
                if (count > 1) {
                   for(int j=0; j<buttonArr.length; j++) {
                      if (buttonArr[j].getLabel().equals(btnText))
                         this.remove(buttonArr[j]);
                   }
                }
            }
            pack();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Tested it right now and it works perfectly!

just quick question, what do you mean by collections?

Comment: for example `ArrayList`, as they provide easier add/remove methods etc : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm

Comment: Thanks @funkyjelly

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this (code may have syntax errors)?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        String btnText = ((Button)e.getSource()).getLabel();

        List<Button> btnList = new ArrayList<Button>();
        for(int i=0; i<buttonArr.length; i++) {
            if (buttonArr[i].getLabel().equals(btnText)) {
                btnList.add(buttonArr[i]);
                //this.remove(buttonArr[i]);
                //pack();
            }
        }
        if (btnList.size() > 1) {
            for (Iterator<Button> it = btnList.iterator(); it.hasNext()) {
                this.remove(it.next());
            }
            pack();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but @funkyjelly posted what needed :)
Thanks!